# Create a subweb using REST in SPFx: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, spfx, spfx-webparts

I am trying to create a classic subweb using a POST REST call in SPFx.
Any idea what I am doing wrong here?

```
  const postURL: string = `${this.props.context.siteUrl}/_api/web/webinfos/add`;

  const requestBody: any = {
     'parameters': {
     '__metadata': {
     'type': 'SP.WebInfoCreationInformation'
     },
     'Url': this.props.context.siteUrl + '/' + title,
     'Description': 'Subsite created from REST API',
     'Title': title,
     'Language': 1033,
     'WebTemplate': 'B7A00BA4-AFDC-4E70-B137-10DAEBED4D8B#TemplateName',
     'UseUniquePermissions': true
    }
    };

   const requestHeaders: any = {
    'Accept': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
    'Content-type': 'application/json;odata=verbose',
    'odata-version': '3.0',
    "X-HTTP-Method": "POST"
   };

  const spOpts: ISPHttpClientOptions = {
    headers: requestHeaders,
    body: JSON.stringify(requestBody)
  };

 console.log("About to make REST API request.");

 this.props.context.spHttpClient.post(
 postURL,
 SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
 spOpts);
```

Error message: Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using the Title value itself in the `Url` parameter. It doesnt accept full url.

Secondly, you dont need to use `requestHeaders`. It will be taken care of by the framework itself.

Modify the code as below:

```
const postURL: string = `${this.props.context.siteUrl}/_api/web/webinfos/add`;

#modify this as per your code
const title = "TestNew5";

const spOpts: ISPHttpClientOptions = {
  body: `{
    "parameters":{
          "@odata.type": "#SP.WebInfoCreationInformation",
          "Title": "${title}", 
          "Url": "${title}",
          "Description": "Subsite created from REST API",
          "Language": 1033,
          "WebTemplate": "B7A00BA4-AFDC-4E70-B137-10DAEBED4D8B#TemplateName",
          "UseUniquePermissions": true
        }
      }`
};

this.props.context.spHttpClient.post(
      postURL,
      SPHttpClient.configurations.v1,
      spOpts).then((response: SPHttpClientResponse) => {

      response.json().then((responseJSON: JSON) => {
          console.log(responseJSON);
      });
});
```